# Windows Forms Editor Exception

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2013, dotnetbar

I'm not even sure how to ask this question, but here goes.  The design view of my windows forms object now crashes with the following error:

> The control DevComponents.DotNetBar.Office2007RibbonForm has thrown an unhandled exception in the designer and has been disabled.
>                 Exception:  Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.  Parameter name:  index
>                 Stack trace:
>                   at DevComponents.DotNetBar.Office2007RibbonForm.WindowsMessageStyleChanged(Message&
>        m)
>                 at
>                 DevComponents.DotNetBar.Office2007RibbonForm.WndProc(Message & m)

When the error page pops up, it is this:

[image: Error Image]

I can't think of anything I did before this happened, which is very frustrating. The last thing I did was this:

1. Add Button on Ribbon Control
2. Double-Clicked the button to add code
3. Realized I forgot to name the button, so removed the event code
4. clicked back on the form tab and BAM. Error.

I tried the following to fix:

- Went back and did an undo on the code (re-added the event for that button).  But didn't help.
- Edited the Designer.vb file to remove that button entirely.  Still didn't help.

I thought about pasting my designer code here... I will if that makes sense, but it is so huge I wasn't sure if that was worthwhile.  Maybe the above error makes sense to someone besides me???

**** EDIT:  Forgot to mention the application runs fine.  Just can't edit the form anymore.

Comment: Editing the designer file should work (only recommended as a last resort though). I suspect there's still a trace of it in there, somewhere.

Comment: I've looked all over the place :(  I commented out the button completely.  Both the original name ButtonItem19 and the new name btnSendTestEmail.  Still errors out.

Answer (score 1):

OK.  I found it.  For some reason the form duplicated the style on the ribbon control.  Even though the error didn't seem like that one.

FYI - I just kept commenting out stuff in the designer and then trying to launch the form until the error went away.  When I finally got to the ribboncontrol, I saw that there were 2 statements:

```
'Me.RibbonControl1.Office2007ColorTable = DevComponents.DotNetBar.Rendering.eOffice2007ColorScheme.Silver
```

and

```
Me.RibbonControl1.Style = DevComponents.DotNetBar.eDotNetBarStyle.StyleManagerControlled
```

As you can see, I commented out the first one and everything worked.